# Getting error while executing grass algorithms from PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, r.watershed

I am trying to run r.water.outlet by PyQGIS but getting grass folder not configured error

I have QGIS 2.18 installed and Grass is not installed on windows 10 and I am able to use r.water.outlet from **Processing>Toolbox>r.water.outlet** but getting error for using it by PyQGIS below code

```
from qgis.core import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import processing
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

watershedLayer =registry.mapLayersByName('Gondala_AET-PET')[0]


xmin =  watershedLayer.extent().xMinimum()
xmax = watershedLayer.extent().xMaximum()
ymin = watershedLayer.extent().yMinimum()
ymax = watershedLayer.extent().yMaximum()


processing.runalg('grass:r.water.outlet',  'Drainage direction' , 695991.202933 , 2180877.920948 ,"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
    0.0,'b') # 'Drainage direction' is layer name in layer panel
```

Below is window pop up after running this script.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to , [the qgis doc](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html#grass)

> the path to the GRASS folder has to be defined, but only if you are
>   running Windows. Additionally, a shell interpreter (usually msys.exe,
>   which can be found in most GRASS for Windows distributions) has to be
>   defined and its path set up as well.

To do this, go to the "processing" tab > and "Options" > "Providers" > GRASS etc..[image] .

This is a print screen on macOS, so you should set your path correctly according to your windows install.